# can I combine server and client models?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-client-side

I've been googling everywhere and can't find answer to this simple question... can I combine server and client models? What if I want server-side for some things (like database access) but client-side for other responsive controls. Why should I be forced into javascript just because I'm running server-side Blazor core?

Comment: the best advice I can give you is to simply sit down and take some quality time to read from the docs - https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/aspnet/web-apps/blazor

Comment: as for your question, we dealing with coding issues, so if you have a problem with your code (exceptions, unpredictable behavior, etc.) - edit your question or ask another one. You may also find this link useful: [ask]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Blazor server-side and Blazor client-side (WebAssembly) are different hosting models and cannot be used simultaneously.